# AtomicBoolean not getting updated

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm implementing a standard Producer-Consumer program such that producer stops after producing 200 products. To signal this, producer puts -1 to the BlockingQueue variable, which otherwise always contains positive integers.
My consumer implementation is as below :

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{
private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
private AtomicBoolean isProducerClosed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);

        while(!isProducerClosed.get()) {
            try {
                Integer value = queue.take();

                if ((value.intValue() == -1)){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Encountered -1. Signal to shutdown consumers.");
                    //isProducerClosed.set(true);
                    isProducerClosed.compareAndSet(false, true);
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consuming : " + value);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Alternate consumer logic (still getting same issue) :

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            Integer value = null;

            synchronized (this) {
                if(!isProducerClosed.get()) {
                    value = queue.take();
                    if ((value.intValue() == -1)) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Encountered -1. Signal to shutdown consumers.");
                        isProducerClosed.set(true);
                        isProducerClosed = isProducerClosed;
                        System.out.println("Current value of isProducerClosed : " + isProducerClosed.get());
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!isProducerClosed.get()) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consuming : " + value);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

While executing this, my consumer threads get stuck on `queue.take()` as if they are waiting for a product to be available in the queue. One possibility could be : all consumer threads checked the condition `isProducerClosed.get()` at the same time, entered the while loop, and access `queue.take()` method. Is this correct assumption? If yes, is there any way to implement this without using low level `synchronized` keyword?
I tried the same thing with `volatile boolean` variable and the result was exactly same. Only after making that variable static, was i able to see all consumers getting terminated after encountering -1 in the queue (as the var is now class-owned).

My calling code :

```
public class ProducerConsumer {

private BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10);


public void executeProducerConsumer(int producerCount, int consumerCount){
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());

    for(int i = 0; i < producerCount; i++) {
        executorService.submit(new Producer(sharedQueue));      //producer
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < consumerCount; i++) {
        executorService.submit(new Consumer(sharedQueue));      //i-th consumer.
    }


    //initiates clossure of threads after completion, in async manner.
    executorService.shutdown();

    //wait till all threads are done.
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("The End.");
}
```

}

Producer code :

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
private volatile int maxNumberOfItemsToProduce = 10;

public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Random random = new Random();

    while(true){

        if(maxNumberOfItemsToProduce == 0) {
            try {
                queue.put(-1);
                System.out.println("Terminating Producer after producing max number of products.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }

        try {
            queue.put(random.nextInt(300));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        maxNumberOfItemsToProduce--;
    }

}
```

}

Screenshot of console:
[image]

Comment: "my consumer threads get stuck on queue.take() as if they are waiting for a product to be available in the queue" - Does your producer actually put something in the queue? This is what a blocking queue does when there is nothing to be consumed. Can you post your producer code?

Comment: "all consumer threads checked the condition isProducerClosed.get() at the same time" - also this shouldn't be the case as the AtomicBoolean is a instance variable.

Comment: @kjsebastan : added producer code (10 products added in queue, after which producer thread exists/stops). Also added screenshot of the console which shows state of the program after encountering -1 value.

Comment: @kjsebastian : if AtomicBoolean is instance variable, then does it mean every thread maintains a copy of this variable (thread stack) and thats why value updated in Thread1's copy is not seen by Thread2? Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One possibility could be : all consumer threads checked the condition isProducerClosed.get() at the same time, entered the while loop, and access queue.take() method. Is this correct assumption? If yes, is there any way to implement this without using low level synchronized keyword? I tried the same thing with volatile boolean variable and the result was exactly same. Only after making that variable static, was i able to see all consumers getting terminated after encountering -1 in the queue (as the var is now class-owned).

Yes, the assumption is true.

First problem is : `isProducerClosed` is NOT shared across consumers. It has to be shared across consumers, so that if one comsumer sets its value, other consumers can see that value too. Making it `static` makes it shared and hence the situation improves after that

Second problem: even after `isProducerClosed` is shared, you may get into a situation where multiple consumers would execute `queue.take()` on a empty queue (a thread may take the last value, but another thread by execute `take()` before the first one sets `isProducerClosed` to true). You will need to synchronize this (e.g. by using double-checking)

Sample code (still contains bugs/races in parts other than the consumer) -

```
public class TestClass {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.executeProducerConsumer(3, 3);
    }

    public void executeProducerConsumer(int producerCount, int consumerCount) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(producerCount + consumerCount, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());

        for (int i = 0; i < producerCount; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Producer(sharedQueue));      //producer
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < consumerCount; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Consumer(sharedQueue));      //i-th consumer.
        }

        //initiates clossure of threads after completion, in async manner.
        executorService.shutdown();

        //wait till all threads are done.
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("The End.");
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private static volatile boolean isProducerClosed = false; // make this static so that it is shared across consumers

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            Integer value;

            while (!isProducerClosed) {
                try {
                    synchronized (queue) { //synchronize so that only one thread can talk to the queue at a time
                        if (!isProducerClosed) { //double check
                            value = queue.take(); // we can now safely take an item
                            if ((value.intValue() == -1)) {
                                isProducerClosed = true;
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Encountered -1. Signal to shutdown consumers.");
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Last item was taken by some other consumer. Exiting!");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    consumeValue(value); //Consume the value outside the lock
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void consumeValue(Integer value) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Consuming value :" + value);
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private static volatile int maxNumberOfItemsToProduce = 10;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();

        while (true) {

            if (maxNumberOfItemsToProduce == 0) {
                try {
                    queue.put(-1);
                    System.out.println("Terminating Producer after producing max number of products.");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }

            try {
                queue.put(random.nextInt(300));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            maxNumberOfItemsToProduce--;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to synchronize operations on a BlockingQueue. That's the whole point of a data structure like this. Excerpt from the javadocs - "BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control."

Comment: The queue itself, as an individual data-structure, is thread-safe. But your situation is different. Once a single consumer detects a specific situation, you want other consumers to not even talk to the queue. Therefore, you have to make sure that once some consumer notices that situation, other consumers would stop talking to the queue instantly, this needs some sort of synchronization/co-ordination among the cosumers (there are many ways to achieve this, I can post a sample if that helps)

Comment: Thanks @AshutoshA. I tried to implement the logic in 'Alternate consumer logic ' section, but that didn't work. Could you please share a solution/psedo-code?

Comment: Added sample code for a solution (better solutions may exist). Note that you need to perform similar corrections in the producer as-well (as it is now, it may enqueue more than the limit)

Comment: @AshutoshA : +1 for pointing out the producer issue for multi-threaded producer.

Comment: This is one solution, but you can avoid the whole locking and separate flag by simply adding the sentinel back to the queue when you get it. Simplifies the logic.